# Is it possible to remove an entry from a NodeList without converting it to an array or destroying the DOM node?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator, javascript-objects

Okay, so I'm working on a method that accepts any form of iterable as its argument. I'd like to perform what amounts to a `splice` on the parameter, but - and this is the crucial bit - without changing its Symbolic Type. That is to say, I'd like the return value's Symbol to match that of the input (NodeList, DOMTokenList, HTMLCollection, etc.)

Contrived Example:

```
let iterableList = document.querySelectorAll('p'); 
// Result: Nodelist(5): p, p.body, p.body, p, p
```

**Assumptions**

1. Assume I wish to remove those two `<p class="body">` tags (from the COLLECTION, *NOT* the DOM).
2. Assume `iterableList` is user-provided (e.g. I cannot simply alter the query to read `p:not(.body)`)
3. Assume we do not know what kind of iterator is the input (i.e. in this example, by virtue of the fact it was a `querySelectorAll` that produced our results, it is a  `NodeList`. Conversely, if it had been a `getElementsByTagName` it would be a `HTMLCollection`. Or any of a half dozen others)
4. Assume the return value should have the same Symbol as the input.
5. Assume I chose this example *because* the results are live nodes (and we *know* the subset *could have* come from a `querySelectorAll('p:not(.body)')`, so we know the subset *is possible*)

**1. Now, obviously I can convert the symbol to an Array...**

...through any number of means. I could then remove the two offending nodes, again by a variety of tactics. The problem is then my return value is an Array, and I've killed off the live node correspondence within the browser.

**2. I could clone just the desired nodes...**

...into a document `fragment` or similar, then re-query the fragment to return just the subset, but then I'd be targeting clones of the DOM nodes in question, not really those themselves, plus it would shake free any event bindings they had once had.

**3a. I could insert a DOM node, `append` the array nodes I wish to keep, then query THAT, then put them back again, and destroy the inserted node...**

... which keeps the nodes in tact (replete with any events bound to them) and even auto-remaps their xPaths to their original DOM locations...

**3b. ...or even use the unique attributes of each node to attempt to dynamically construct a selector that matched only those I wished to keep...**

...but because I don't know the Symbolic Type of iterator the collection is prior to receiving it, I would need a massive collection of such workarounds to conditionally handle each of the possibilities (and that's entirely notwithstanding the fact it'd be a bicycle-tire-with-a-banana solution that I'D never let through code review, either).

***So I guess my question is:***

> *Is* there a way to modify, selectively clone, or even iteratively construct such an output? I don't need to perform any operation other than REMOVING one or more of the offending nodes; no edits or inserts.

A `for...of` statement will let one iterate them without conversion to the Array prototype, although I'm not aware of a way to call the Iterator constructors on the fly, even if I could figure out a way to move one of the live nodes from one collection to the other (the spread operator coerces the collection into an array).

Anyone know any good voodoo for this one? Or am I just SOL here?

Comment: `The problem is then my return value is an Array, and I've killed off the live node correspondence within the browser.` Just curious, what do you mean by that exactly? What do you lose?

Comment: Only that in its initial state it's what's called a "live list'. Means that if the DOM gets mutated the list itself automatically is updated. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#live_vs._static_nodelists

Comment: And, to be fair: it's the least significant element of the question; merely worth noting.

Comment: It might be a live list, yes, but not if you use querySelectorAll for instance. Also, if this is the least significant part, then the answer is simple: use an array

Comment: Since the question is, quite literally, "is it possible to manipulate this collection WITHOUT converting it to an array," I would argue that's not really answering it.

Comment: Sure, but in that case the answer is simply "no" (it's not possible)

Comment: And it's wholly possible that IS the answer. I'm hoping someone that knows more than I do on the topic might have a trick or some knowledge I do not. Also, side note: the symbolic type of a `querySelectorAll` IS a NodeList it's just a static one. But a `document.body.childNodes` is a live list, and a possible iterable.

Comment: With "*accepts any form of iterable as its argument.*" and "*return [the same type as] the input (NodeList, DOMTokenList, HTMLCollection, etc)*", this is impossible. If all you know is that the input is iterable, and since iterables have no `splice`-like method returning themselves, all you can do is to return the input value itself

Comment: @Bergi yeah, that's what I was afraid of. I even went so far as to try to extend the underlying prototypes themselves to see if I might not sneak such a method in under the hood, but no dice there either. C'est la vie.

Comment: Old question, but what would be the arguments you pass to *slice*? It would be good if the question had an example of this with expected output. Mostly for live collections, the slice could be ambiguous. If a slice is defined by indices, like with the `.slice()` array method, then what happens if the live collection gets an additional element within that slice? Does the slice grow, or does the slice drop its last element to keep with the given indices? Examples would be helpful.